# Apply custom function to multiple data.table columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lapply

I have written the function below that takes a non-standard time format e.g. '730' (7:30) and converts it to a decimal number of hours e.g. '7.5'.

```
decimal_time <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  tmp <- nchar(x)

  if (tmp < 4 & !is.na(tmp)){
    x <- paste0(strrep('0',4-tmp),as.character(x))
  }

  x <-  sub("([[:digit:]]{2,2})$", ":\\1", x)
  x <- strsplit(x,':')[[1]]
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x[1]+x[2]/60
}
```

To apply it to one column I do the following...

```
dt_times[, New_Time := lapply(Time, decimal_time)]
```

However I can't figure out how to apply this same function to many columns that share the same format. Of course, if it was a vectorised function (like 'mean') then I could just write...

```
dt_times[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = c('col1', 'col2')]
```

... but what do I do if my function uses lapply in the first place?! Help please!

Comment: `dt_times[, c('col1', 'col2') := lapply(.SD, decimal_time), .SDcols = c('col1', 'col2')]`?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work - I get the results for the first row on every row...

Comment: " In if (tmp < 4 & !is.na(tmp)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is that you have not a vectorised function, then you could use sapply inside the function

```
decimal_time <- function(y) {
  sapply(y,function(x) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    tmp <- nchar(x)

    if (tmp < 4 & !is.na(tmp)){
      x <- paste0(strrep('0',4-tmp),as.character(x))
    }

    x <-  sub("([[:digit:]]{2,2})$", ":\\1", x)
    x <- strsplit(x,':')[[1]]
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[1]+x[2]/60
  })
}
```

Comment: That's a brilliant work-around thank you! Is there a way that I could've handled the strings so that it was intrinsically vectorised? Or is that kind of manipulation a common problem?

Comment: Personally, I have always done like that when I had this problem. There must be a way but I couldn't figure it out yet

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any loops (outside or inside the function). You can fully vectorize your function:

```
decimal_time <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  tmp <- nchar(x)
  ii <- tmp < 4 & !is.na(tmp)
  x[ii] <- paste0(strrep('0',4-tmp[ii]), x[ii])

   x <-  sub("([[:digit:]]{2,2})$", ":\\1", x)
  x <-  strsplit(x,':')
  x <- do.call(rbind, x)
  mode(x) <- "numeric"
  x[,1]+x[,2]/60
}

x <- c("1", "730")
decimal_time(x)
#[1] 0.01666667 7.50000000
```

Using integer division it's even easier than with text processing:

```
decimal_time <- function(x) {
  x <- as.integer(x)
  if (any(x >= 2400)) warning("input >= 24 h")
  x %/% 100 + (x %% 100) / 60
}

x <- c("1", "730")
decimal_time(x)
#[1] 0.01666667 7.50000000
```

Comment: I actually needed to do  

`ii <- which(tmp < 4 & !is.na(tmp))`  then  
 `x[ii] <- paste0(strrep('0',4-tmp[ii]), x[ii])`  

but that worked thanks!

Comment: I think instead of text processing you should use integer division and modulo.

Comment: I've added what I would use.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I've encountered in the past. My solution is typically to just run a `for` loop:

```
for(col in c('col1', 'col2'){
 dt_times[, (col):= vapply(col, function(x) decimal_time(get(x)), FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))]
}
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it should get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you to use the `map_dfr` function from the `purrr` package to apply a function over data.frame, returning a data.frame as well. Under the hood, the map_* family of functions iterate the same as using for loops, but in a more readable and tidy way.

Also, if you'd like to map this function to specific column names you could as well use the `dplyr` package as well, combining the use of the `filter` and `contains` functions, you can modify those specific variables. Combining these features:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  filter(contains("some_string")) %>%
  map_dfr(decimal_time)
```

Comment: Thanks but this question is tagged as data.table for a reason :)

Comment: Sorry I jumped the data.table tag, thought it could have been a good alternative. Thanks